# Prevent checking condition if object is null

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

In short:
User can have own permissions. User can be also assigned to grup, which contains permissions. Now I want to check if user have permission `x`, or group which he is in have that permission. User can be in no group.

```
viewModel.PermissionControllers = permissionControllers.Select(x => new PermissionControlerViewModel
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.ControllerName,
    Description = x.Desciption,
    Actions = x.PermissionActions.Select(a => new PermissionAction
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        Name = a.Name,
        Description = a.Description
        IsSelected = user.ActionPermissions.Any(p => p.PermissionActionId == a.Id) || user.Group.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id),
    }).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

If `user.ActionPermissions.Any(p => p.PermissionActionId == a.Id)` returns `false`, and `user.Group` is `null` I am getting `argument null exception`. I tried something like this:

```
user.Group?.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id)
```

But I am getting error:

```
Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'bool?'
```

What can I do there?

Comment: What happens if you change `user.Group?.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id)` to `(user.Group?.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id) ?? false)` (or `true` - depending on the behaviour you want)?

Comment: or use `user.Group?.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id) == true` :)

Comment: is there a getvalueordefault to the any function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) buys you is that it returns `null`, instead of trying to access properties on a `null` reference and throwing an exception.

So what you kinda end up with is something like this:

```
IsSelected = false || null;
```

You need to provide a default value in the event that the `Group` is `null`:

```
// provide a value to use if the first result is null, using a null coalescer
IsSelected = user.ActionPermissions.Any(p => p.PermissionActionId == a.Id)
             || (user.Group?.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id) ?? false)

// if it's supported in your situation, you may be able to use HasValue
IsSelected = user.ActionPermissions.Any(p => p.PermissionActionId == a.Id)
             || (user.Group.HasValue && user.Group.GroupActionPermissions.Any(z => z.PermissionActionId == a.Id))
```